# Run 2 Behat profiles with different features into 1 result

Tags: bash, behat, exit-code

I have 2 very different Behat profiles:

```
simple:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - rdx\behatvars\BehatVariablesContext
        - SimpleFeatureContext
  extensions:
      rdx\behatvars\BehatVariablesExtension: ~
proxy:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - ProxyFeatureContext
```

`simple` loads one local Context, `proxy` loads another. `simple` must have the extension, `proxy` must not.

Combined, they run tests that should pass entirely. Currently, this is my `run-tests` script:

```
vendor/bin/behat --profile=proxy --format-settings='{"paths":false}' features/proxy.feature &&
echo &&
vendor/bin/behat --profile=simple --format-settings='{"paths":false}' features/simple.feature
```

Not only is it ugly, it doesn't work properly. The `&&` make sure the right result is passed on to the `run-tests` caller, but they also mean the 2nd tests isn't run if the 1st test fails.

How do I keep both:

- Both tests must run
- The exit code must be the last fail (or `1` if any fails)

I don't want to make `run-tests` more complicated, so this is more a Behat question than Bash. Can I tell Behat to run 2 profiles with separate features and return the combined result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
result=0
cmds1 || result=$?
echo
cmds2 || result=$?
exit $result
```

If one of the commands fail, the exit code from the failure is propagated to the caller. (If both fail, the last failure is the one we pass back to the caller.) When a test succeeds, we don't touch the `result` variable. If both succeed, it remains at zero (success).

Comment: That makes the test script more complicated. I'm looking for a Behat solution.

Comment: If the script is parsed by Bash, I don't see a way to make your existing script do what you are asking for.  I also don't think this is more complicated.  This extends readily to more tests, and is easy to grasp once you grok the basic idea.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with Behat, though. The unholy mix of YAML and JSON I see above makes me think maybe it's better that way; but certainly, this answer is a shot in the dark, and if you don't think it's suitable at all, I'll be more than happy to delete it.

Comment: It's suitable, but I'm still wishing for a fully Behat solution =) It's worse than just an "unholy mix of YAML and JSON", but it's also pretty damn cool. Thanks so far!

Comment: ... Oh, PHP. Better stay clear. Thanks for following up.